# putExtra camera made my app crash, how can i fix it?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE)); // set the image file name 
**Why It's make my app clash**

in main activity this command

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE));
```

This code effect to this code

```
startActivityForResult(intent, MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
```

then it made my app crash

you can focus at

```
public void takingPhoto()
public void takingVideo()
```

in function

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.labinclass;


import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Uri fileUri;
    private Button takePhoto;
    private Button takeVideo;
    private Button sharePhoto;
    private ImageView captureImage;
    private Intent intent;
    private Bitmap bp;

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        takePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takePhoto);
        takeVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takeVideo);
        sharePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sharePhoto);
        captureImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.captureImage);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] {
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
            },110);
        }
            takingPhoto();
            takingVideo();
            shareStory();
    }

    public void takingPhoto() {
        takePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE)); // set the image file name **Why It's Error**
                startActivityForResult(intent, MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }

    public void takingVideo() {
        takeVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)); // set the image file name **Why It's Error**
                startActivityForResult(intent, MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
            }
        });
    }

    public void shareStory(){
        sharePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*String bitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bp,null, null);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath);
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android"); //Instagram App package
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share to"));*/

                Intent showInstagram = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
                startActivity(showInstagram);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                data.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE)); // set the image file name
                bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                captureImage.setScaleType (ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                captureImage.setImageBitmap(bp);
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                android.widget.Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else if (requestCode == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                //How can I Show Video on Phone Screen ?????????????????????????????????

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                android.widget.Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "LabInClass");

        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("LabInClass", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        }
        else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
        return mediaFile;
    }

}
```

and in onActivityResult can I show my video on the Telephone screen

**activity_main.xml**

I think is almost correct in this part

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="20"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/captureImage"
    android:rotation="90"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="13"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/takePhoto"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Take Photo"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/takeVideo"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Take Video"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sharePhoto"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Intent Instagram"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidMainfest.xml**

I think is almost correct in this part as same as upper part

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.labinclass">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is my **stack trace**

```
2019-03-28 14:02:52.502 8069-8069/com.example.labinclass E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.labinclass, PID: 8069
    android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/LabInClass/IMG_20190328_140252.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1958)
        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2359)
        at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:941)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9756)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9741)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1611)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4479)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4437)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:751)
        at com.example.labinclass.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:74)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6274)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24859)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Please, post exception stacktrace if logcat contains it.